# Displaying some data in Grid according to boolean value using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, gridview, redux, boolean

I want to display "Taxable" if value from db is **true**, if value is **false**  print "Non-Taxable".
How can I do it in react-redux?
Following is the code I tried.

```
render : (text,record) => record.IsTaxable === true ? (
                <span>
                    <label>Taxable</label>
                </span>
            ) : (
                <span>
                    <label>Non-Taxable</label>
                </span>
            )
```

The problem is that only "Non taxable " is printing. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
render : (text,record) =>  (
                    <span>
                        <label>
                         {record.IsTaxable ? "Taxable" : "Non-Taxable"}
                         </label>
                    </span>
                )
```

Comment: Could you print the value of record.isTaxable. I thinks its coming non true always. Because this code is very simple and straightforward. not seems to find any way where it will break

Comment: Let me check if it's any issue from backend

Comment: It's an issue from backed that the value of IsTaxable wasn't passed . Thank you for your help